# HTML / BODY heigh won't adjust to content with sticky footer and opacity layer

Tags: html, opacity

I want the opacity layer to fill out to the bottom unrelated to the amount of content.  So with little content; stretches to the bottom, and with alot of content; stretches to the bottom.

I have tried a vast amount of methods such as `border-box`, `display:block`, and all the others I have found during the last three days trying to figure out just this.

I also tried setting the content to a `min-height:800px`so that it would always show filled even with little content, but the same issue arises for when the content exceeds these 800px.
http://jsfiddle.net/rZkSx/ or the original site with the problem: http://www.fredberentsen.com/fotosafari/index.html

**SHORT VERSION:**
I want the white opacity layer to fill from top to bottom, no matter the size of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the HTML add one div with a class (ex: mask)

```
<div class="mask></div>
```

And in the CSS add the rules to that class

```
.mask {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

I've updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZkSx/1/) aswell.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you _so_ much for doing my day as best as it could be!

Comment: My pleasure :)

PS: Don't forget to set the answer as "Correct".